# How to see that I have pending notifications on Mac?

Tags: notifications, notification-area

Scenario: I wasn't looking at the screen for 2 minutes and few notifications arrived. If I click on the date-time (located on the top right), I can see them. But, I don't know that I have any notifications in order to click there.

Question: **Is there a way to see some indication near the date-time so I know there are notifications there?** Thanks.

Some of the apps implement some counter on their dock app icon, but this isn't good enough as I have the dock in auto-hide mode.

Mac version: 11.2.3 (Bid Sur).

Comment: You could change the banner style from 'Banners' to 'Alerts' then they would stay on-screen until actioned or dismissed

Comment: Tetsujin, I'd like to have the option to choose and not always have the notifications blocking part of the screen.